# Is there a better way to structure this scrape?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

Still learning how to webscrape using BeautifulSoup and Python. I have come up with this to grab the professional experience from this website https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/ali-shahrestani-esq-198352.

```
for item in soup.findAll("dl",attrs={"class":"description-list list-with-badges"}):
    x=item.findAll("strong")
    x=remove_tags(str(x))
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[Attorney]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

I also am looking to get the information under "Attorney" but I am struggling.

Comment: `if x: x[0].find(...)` to get information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter data using `if x:` and later you can do different things with `item`

```
for item in soup.find_all("dl", {"class": "description-list list-with-badges"}):
    x = item.find_all("strong")
    if x:
        print('strong:', x[0].get_text(strip=True))
        print('text:', item.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))
        print('list:', item.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|'))
```

Result

```
strong: Attorney
text: Attorney|Ali Shahrestani, Esq.|2007|- Current
list: ['Attorney', 'Ali Shahrestani, Esq.', '2007', '- Current']
```

Or you can try to use other unique values - ie.

```
<strong itemprop='jobTitle'>
```

and use other function - ie `parent`

```
data = soup.find('strong', {'itemprop': 'jobTitle'}).parent.parent
print('text:', data.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))
print('list:', data.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|'))
```

Result:

```
text: Attorney|Ali Shahrestani, Esq.|2007|- Current
list: ['Attorney', 'Ali Shahrestani, Esq.', '2007', '- Current']
```

---

Full example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/ali-shahrestani-esq-198352'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all("dl", {"class": "description-list list-with-badges"}):
    x = item.find_all("strong")
    if x:
        print('strong:', x[0].get_text(strip=True))
        print('text:', item.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))
        print('list:', item.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|'))

print('---')

item = soup.find('strong', {'itemprop': 'jobTitle'}).parent.parent
print('text:', item.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))
print('list:', item.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|'))
```